# Checkout from svn repository over ssh

Tags: ssh, svn

I'd really like to know how to checkout a SVN repository from a remote machine that is only serving on the svn protocol (so no WebDAV with Apache etc.) over an SSH connection.

Can someone tell me how to do so?

So, here is the situation once more to clarify:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this: http://www.petefreitag.com/item/531.cfm? Specifically, this bit: `svn co svn+ssh://<path to repo>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If your SVN server is not running on the default port 22: add a tunnel entry to `~/.subversion/config`

   Open the file, look for [tunnels] and a line, for example:

   > sshserver = ssh -p *[port where your ssh server is running on]* -q

   For everybody: add -q if you're getting 'Killed by signal 15' when trying to checkout.
2. Checkout using a absolute path from the remote location

   In this example we use the configured tunnel entry from step 1.

   ```
   svn co svn+sshserver://user@server/absolute/path/to/svn/repository/project/
   ```

More background information:

- [Basic instructions to connect to a SVN-repo over SSH](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Ecrf/crf-guide/resources/software/svn-ssh.html)
- The book [Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.sshauth)

Comment: A rare answer that explicitly shows you have to use the absolute path +1

Answer (score 5):

Why still using svn :-) Try git

Through **ssh**:

`svn co svn+ssh://user@path/to/svn/repo/`

or
`git svn clone svn+ssh://user@path/to/svn/repo/`

Through **https**:

`svn co https://user@path/to/svn/repo/`

or
`git svn clone https://user@path/to/svn/repo/`

When first username is not working, press enter. Then you can enter the correct username.

Comment: Haha, check the original question date ;)

Comment: I know, it's pretty time for everyone to move to git if you haven't done that already. Here we still have svn repos, that's why I came across this solution ;-)

Comment: Just point one 'real' good reason to move to git. SVN is easier, allows to checkout subdirs and do everything git does but distrubuted server. No real reasons to move to it at all.

Comment: Many reasons, `git` also allows checkout of subdirs with 'sparse` checkout. I must say the base of git is easier than svn, no need for a server. Advantages of git over svn are proper branching (not as dirs!), offline support, code sharing, merging/rebasing etc. Btw, the whole world is moving to git. I liked Mercurial even more, but sadly, it's not as popular...